# Syntax errors in VHDL code

Tags: vhdl

Hey guys I was working with VHDL and my problem statement is as below:

**Write a VHDL code for XOR and XNOR functions, same as previous lab session,  and define another input “x” in your code such that if input x=1 then  F = X1 XOR X2, 
else F = X1 XNOR X2.**

So I started writing this code:

```
LIBRARY ieee ;

USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;

ENTITY prework IS

PORT ( x1, x2, x : IN STD_LOGIC ;

f: OUT STD_LOGIC ) ;

END prework ;

ARCHITECTURE LogicFunction OF prework IS


PROCESS (x,x1,x2)
BEGIN
if x = '1' then
    f <= (x1 AND NOT x2) OR (NOT x1 AND x2);
else
    f <= NOT((x1 AND NOT x2) OR (NOT x1 AND x2));
end if;
end PROCESS;

END LogicFunction ;
```

But I keep getting these errors:

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at prework.vhd(16) near text "PROCESS";  expecting "begin", or a declaration statement

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at prework.vhd(20) near text "ELSE";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at prework.vhd(22) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"

So can you please help me solve these errors,
Thank you

Comment: The error message already includes the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `Architecture` statement, you also have to use `Begin`, just like after `Process`. The error is pretty clear on that.

Comment: thank you sir I just started learning vhdl so it was a silly mistake :)